# xDispatch LNK2019 Linker error Unresolved Externals

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I realise this i mighty popular question, but all of the other posts seem to follow the same idea. That the include, lib and bin folder need to be correctly configured. I believe my settings are correct, but i am still getting the LNK2019 error. What am i doing wrong?

Using Visual Studio 2012

I am getting the infamous LNK2019 error. Many posts of this issue seem to think it is a linker issue. I am using a library with lib and dll files. The project folder has an include, bin and lib folder that need to be configured in the project.

Install instructions are here.....
http://opensource.mlba-team.de/xdispatch/docs/current/tutorial.html

However, this is clearly a linker issue as it occurs in other libraries of a similar type. I have followed the instructions for other posts and i'm still a bit lost. I believe this should be correct, but i have tried virtually every possible combination. Don't get it.

My Project Configurations

**C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.**
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LibDispatchTest\xdispatch_0.7.2_Visual Studio 10_i386\include;%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

**Linker -> General -> Additional Library Directories**
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\LibDispatchTest\xdispatch_0.7.2_Visual Studio 10_i386\lib;%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories)

**Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependancies:**
.....uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;xdispatch.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

Environment Variables.

I have the PATH variable set.

C:\Chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\VisionBase\xdispatch_0.7.2_Visual Studio 10_i386\bin;

The error messages are:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "_declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall xdispatch::queue::async(class std::function<void __cdecl(void)> const &)" (__imp?async@queue@xdispatch@@QAEXABV?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl some_function(void)" (?some_function@@YAXXZ)   c:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\LibDispatchTest\LibDispatchTest\main.obj  LibDispatchTest 

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals   c:\users\daniel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\LibDispatchTest\Debug\LibDispatchTest.exe 1   1   LibDispatchTest
```

Seriously, am totally lost and i do not see what i am doing wrong here.

EDIT 1

This is similar to a sample from the above link, but modified to just couNT 1000000^2 and print some stuff. We just want to be able to compile and run this sample and i can correct my larger project exhibiting this issue. This project was made fresh with the simplest code that is representative of what i need to get working. Both this sample and my other project have this problem and produce the same error.

```
#include <xdispatch/dispatch>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

class SomeData {    
public:      
std::vector<double> a;   
std::vector<double> b;   
std::vector<double> c;   
std::vector<double> results;  
};

void do_calculations(SomeData* sd){

       // our output will go in here
       sd->results = std::vector<double>(sd->a.size());

       // the calculation - running on one thread only
       for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++){
              sd->results[i] = 0;
              for(unsigned int j = 0; j < 10000000; j++){
                     for(unsigned int z = 0; z < sd->c.size(); z++){
                            std::cout << i << " " << j << std::endl;
                     }
              }
       } }

/*  This function is getting called  from your main thread also powering  the user interface  */ 

void some_function() {
           SomeData* sd = new SomeData();       
           xdispatch::global_queue().async(${

                  // execute the heavy code
                  do_calculations(sd);
           }); } 

int main() {    
some_function();
    return 0; }
```

Is anyone able to help?

Comment: No way to help you, if you don't show the exact error.

Comment: Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: void __thiscall xdispatch::queue::async(class std::function<void __cdecl(void)> const &)" (__imp_?async@queue@xdispatch@@QAEXABV?$function@$$A6AXXZ@std@@@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl some_function(void)" (?some_function@@YAXXZ) c:\Users\Daniel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\LibDispatchTest\LibDispatchTest\main.obj LibDispatchTest

Comment: Error 2 error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals c:\users\daniel\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\LibDispatchTest\Debug\LibDispatchTest.exe 1 1 LibDispatchTest

Comment: Apologies, i had assumed from what i've read that this is typically the place where the problem occurs and the error seems to confirm this but does not provide anything i recognize as useful in resolving this, given the failure of my attempts using advice from other posts.

Comment: Linker-> System -> SubSystemConsole (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE)

Comment: You should also show the code of `someFunction()`, where and how you call this stuff from xdispatch (not in comments, **edit your question** please!).

Comment: Most probably XDspatch queue doesn't support the signature you're trying: `xdispatch::queue::async(class std::function<void __cdecl(void)> const &)`. Did you check your code is correct? It's a template I'd guess (so no problem from the libs linked).

Comment: Well, it is pretty much the same as the example from their site. The async function is the function that causes this problem. When it is commented out, the problem goes away.

Comment: What's that weird `${` stuff? Did you want to define a lambda function? Is this a visual studio extension?

Comment: This is a libdispatch feature. Seems to be related to their async stuff.

Comment: Yeah, I've checked the sample from their site. Wasn't aware that `$` could be used as cpp macro name.

Comment: So, this has me beat i think.

Comment: I've tried adding the dlls to the execution folder also. No joy.

Comment: DLLs are linked using corresponding `.lib` stubs. No need to have them available for linking.

Comment: Hmmm. I've sent a link to this thread to xDispatch mailing list, but really this is odd. For their benefit, i am using Visual Studio 2012 with Windows 7. I am using the Windows – x86 download of xDispatch.

Comment: You are aware that their project needs full c++11 support? I'm not so sure that VS2012 will fit all of these requirements.

Comment: Well, the last release was for VS2010. "Archive containing release and debug libraries for win32 applications using MS Visual Studio 2010". So i'd assume it'd work for 2012.

Comment: @user2723463 You may want to consider taking down the cash reward offer. [It's not generally considered a good idea](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25615/offering-actual-money-as-a-bounty), and might get your question closed. If you're that desperate, let me know (ping me by including `@computerfreaker` in a comment) and I'll [start a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) on your question. You don't have enough rep to do that yourself, but I'm willing to help you out.

Comment: @computerfreaker thank you for your response. I will look into the bounty system, to understand how it works and then ping you again.

Comment: @user2723463 In a nutshell - you sacrifice a certain amount of rep to get your question onto the `Featured Questions` tab. You can then award that amount of rep to a particularly good answer (generally whatever answer you accept). The minimum award is 50 rep, though, and you only have 16 right now. I don't mind giving you 50 rep for your cause, though.

Comment: @computerfreaker I would be very grateful. If you ever need any asp .net or opencv work doing i could return the favour.

Comment: @user2723463 No problem. Best of luck with your question! If you do get a good answer, please ping me when you accept it so I remember to award the bounty. I don't think I'll be notified of answers otherwise, and I'm not familiar with xDispatch so I won't recognize a good answer.

Comment: @computerfreaker Thank you so much. I promise to fulfill the deal. :)

Comment: @computerfreaker Thumbs up! Altruism is a good thing to do!

Comment: @user2723463 Just a reminder for you, the bounty just ended. Please let me know if user20140327's answer is acceptable so I know whether to award the bounty or not; if I don't hear from you within a reasonable time (I have just under 23 hours to award the bounty) I'll just award it, since the answer seems reasonable enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The binaries you used where built with and for MS Visual Studio 2010. Since then the CRT has changed quite a bit and might not be compatible, especially when parts of the STL is used. Because of that I do not recommend to ever use a C++ dll built with VS 2010 for use in VS 2012 or later. It could be that building and linking succeeds but during runtime you experience weird and unexpected issues. In your case even linking won’t work because std::function has changed its signature in the meantime, so lucky enough you already discover those incompatibilities at compile time.

I assume xdispatch will work just fine with VS2012 and maybe even VS2013, however you will need to do your own build for that. All information needed is summarized at [1]. A tarball containing the sources can always be found at [2].

[1] http://opensource.mlba-team.de/xdispatch/docs/current/requirements.html
[2] http://opensource.mlba-team.de/xdispatch/files/